# Generating Random Letters

Tags: vba, random, powerpoint

I am very new in VBA and honestly no idea of the codes/functions needed to use and what their purpose are but I need to make a PowerPoint that includes a Command Button to create a random letter during the presentation. Can you give me the codes and if possible, explain why use those codes? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few Notes

- This is set up such that it will occur on slide 1.
- The text box which will contain the letter is named: "Random_Letters"
- The active x command button which triggers the macro is named "Generate_Random_Letter"

  ```
   Sub Generate_Random_Letter_Click()

       ' Read this stuff (or dont lol)
       ' vba number to letter (chr) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/character-set-0127
       ' vba random  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function

       Randomize
       Dim upperBound As Integer: upperBound = 90
       Dim lowerBound As Integer: lowerBound = 65
       Dim randomIndex As Integer: randomIndex = Int((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd + lowerBound)


       Dim p As Presentation: Set p = ActivePresentation
       Dim s As Slide: Set s = p.Slides.Item(1)
       Dim t As Shape: Set t = s.Shapes.Item("Random_Letters")
       t.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Chr(randomIndex)

   End Sub
  ```

Good Luck, and remember to actually learn the content.